# How to hide address bar (Navigation bar) for Firefox v29.0?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I've been using Vimperator in Firefox for a long time. I'd like to hide or remove the address bar to get a bigger main window.  However, after update to v29.0, the address bar cannot be hidden or removed.  How can I do that?  Or which add-in can help?

Here is the screenshot of my older version (before v29.0); you can see the address bar has been hidden:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Comment: The question is not asking for _users_ to have their address bar removed, it's asking how to turn off the address bar in one's own Firefox instance with the Vimperator extension. Previous versions of Firefox with Vimperator saved much space by putting all this information in a combined status-bar / command-line, and the address bar becomes unnecessary once you are navigating entirely with the keyboard. It just takes up space.

Comment: @DavidThomas, if you are using `vimperator`, you will NOT suggest me "Don't do this". `Vimperator` will help you do anything (almost) by commands. Tool-bar, Address-bar, Navigation-bar are all "nothing matters"

Comment: Please @Marslo, witch colorsheme are you using?

Comment: Hi @fauve, the Appearance is `FT DeepDark`

Comment: Thank’s. And I think that the vimperator’s colorshem is [darknes](https://github.com/vimpr/vimperator-colors/blob/master/darkness.vimp). I am right?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

What you want is `:set gui=nonavigation`. See http://code.google.com/p/vimperator-labs/issues/detail?id=943

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've tried `:set gui=nonavigation` but nothing happens... I've tried using a addin [Hide Navigation Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-navigation-bar/), but this addin needs be triggered, and "address bar (navigation bar)" shows again if the mouse move to tab, it's truly annoy....

Comment: Cool!!! I found that, after remove the `Hide Navigation Bar`, the setting of `vimperatorrc` works!!! Thanks!!

Comment: but when i restarted the browser, it is visible again, how to fix this?

Comment: @Sekar put the command in your .vimperatorrc file like Marslo mentioned.

Comment: .vimperatorrc file location in ubuntu?

Comment: Just save it as `~/.vimperatorrc`. Create it if it doesn't exist. Alternatively, you can use `:mkvimperatorrc` from within vimperator, which will create the file and save all current settings (including `:set gui=nonavigation` if you have called it).